# Calling IB API from Python

Tags: c++, python, boost, swig, py++

IB = Interactive Brokers

There seem to be two main choices

1. SWIG
2. Boost.Python + Py++

I understand the relative merits or demerits of using these two methods to some extent. But almost all discussions (in SO) talk about which of these tools would be better for a complex task. What I want to ask is, which of these two should I use for just passing some data to a c++ routine which then calls the API?

I guess I am just asking about the learning curve!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBpy is a great solution it's a wrapper built on the java version of the API.

http://code.google.com/p/ibpy/

Comment: The current version of IB API is API 9.68, but ibPy only supports API 9.51.

Comment: I use ibpy with the current (constantly updating) version of IB's API and it works fine for me. However I couldn't get the standard version mentioned in the answer working, and instead use https://github.com/blampe/IbPy. There's a small tutorial I used on 
http://www.quantstart.com/articles/Using-Python-IBPy-and-the-Interactive-Brokers-API-to-Automate-Trades

Answer (score 1):

Can I propose a 3rd choice? In term of learning curve [pyCxx](http://cxx.sourceforge.net/) is excellent. I think it is lighter than SWIG or Boost. It might be interesting for you. You can look at the examples to start a 1st module.

I've used it with success in the past and I found it easy to use.

I hope it helps

Comment: pyCxx is interesting. currently I am looking into pyCxx and apache thrift - http://thrift.apache.org/ . thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

This version of ibpy works for me with the latest versions of the IB API (as of July 2014 anyway): https://github.com/blampe/IbPy

I've been using it successfully for months now. All I had to do was clone ibpy somewhere:

```
git clone https://github.com/blampe/IbPy
```

and install from there:

```
cd IbPy
python setup.py install
```

I got this originally from http://www.quantstart.com/articles/Using-Python-IBPy-and-the-Interactive-Brokers-API-to-Automate-Trades

Once you've got that installed, the interface in python is pretty much identical to the Java API interface: [IB API pdf](http://www.interactivebrokers.com/download/newMark/PDFs/APIprintable.pdf)

I found it useful to look at the TWS Test Client Java code included with the IB API.